# Kernel - networking, role of the "private" structure

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

#### Context

Reading the Linux device driver book, chapter 17.

I don't quite understand why one would need a private structure to hold information.

I don't get it, its usage.

The pci_device and net_device structure already have plenty of information.

Can someone tell me more ?

Comment: Most drivers use a pointer to a private struct to hold device-specific information or something that doesn't belong in the general bus-device struct but is still needed.

Comment: You are right Peter +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the book, It has been suggested that direct access of these information will deteriorate system performance and also has flexibility issue. So we use private structure to encourage the use of functions to access these information.

Reference: ch17.13860 Page 504, Linux Device Drivers, Third edition

As far as its uses is concerned. You are free to make its own use of the field or to ignore it. It is a useful resource for preserving state information across system calls.

Comment: Thanks but how do I know what to put there?

Comment: You are free to make its own use of the field or to ignore it. It is a useful resource for preserving state information across system calls.

Comment: understood. it also may avoid reallocation of pointer at every function I guess now. Could you add your comment in your answer so that I can validate it? that is the answer i guess